# MarkLogic upgrade incompatibility (downgrade)

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, downgrade, marklogic-10

I recently upgraded our MarkLogic 9.x.x to 10.x.x (latest version).
We encountered this error:

> XDMP-NESTEDMULTI: xdmp:invoke-function(function() as item()*, query...) -- Cannot create a nested multi-statement transaction inside a multi-statement transaction.

Now our way to resolve this is to downgrade back to 9.x.x our version before the error showed up.

Is there a correct way to downgrade MarkLogic?
or even resolve the error above?

Comment: There's no way to downgrade. Your only option would be to stand up a fresh ML9.x cluster and migrate your documents using something like MLCP. But it seems likely that a future update to ML9 could result in the same error, so probably a better option would be to contact support to help you resolve that error.

Comment: Rather than attempt to downgrade, focus on fixing the issue. It would be easier to help diagnose and suggest changes if you shared the code for that `xdmp:invoke-function()` call.

Comment: I concur with Mads, moving forward is better. Just as general advice, always do a backup before upgrade, so that you can just restore that backup in a fresh ML9 cluster in case you need to go back..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to inspect the code that is causing this error. Look for any eval, invoke, or spawn functions, and see what options have set the **transaction-mode** to `update`.

**transaction-mode**

> [DEPRECATED: Use the `update` and `commit` options instead.] Explicitly set the transaction mode for this context. Allowed values: `auto` (default), `query`, `update-auto-commit`, `update`. For details, see [Transaction Mode](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_25046) in the Application Developer's Guide.
>
> For simple updates to be implicitly committed, specify a transaction mode of `update-auto-commit`. A transaction mode of update creates a new multi-statement update transaction and requires an explicit commit in the code.
>
> Within a session there can be only one active multi-statement transaction at a time. If a new multi-statement transaction is specified nested inside a multi-statement transaction, MarkLogic throws the exception **XDMP-NESTEDMULTI**.

https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-NESTEDMULTI

**Cause**

An eval or invoke with transaction-mode `update` was attempted in a multi-statement transaction.

**Response**

Use transaction-mode `update-auto-commit` instead.